# file permisions wamp vs host

Tags: linux, wamp

i  have a script which create some files and zips them, 
works fine on  my local dev env. WAMP.

does'nt create the files on my host, i have manually change the folder permissions to 777 
via filezilla for the parent folder.

still does not help . what else could i try ?

```
$db = 'halaalre_rt'; //get the db
    //$db = 'hmzcms'; //get the db
    $file_names = array();

    $showtablequery_result  = $this->DBopen->query("SHOW TABLES FROM $db");//get tables list
    while($showtablerow = $showtablequery_result->fetch_array())
        {
        $table_name = $showtablerow[0];

        $backup_file  = BASEDIR.'/tmp/backup/'.$table_name.'.sql';//creat file name
        $this->DBopen->query("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backup_file' FROM $table_name");//createe files
        }

    $this->Zip(BASEDIR.'/tmp/backup/', './compressed.zip');
    return $this->Data;
```

Comment: Isn't this a question better suited for your hosting provider help desk?

Comment: try changing permission recursively for folder & subfolders.

Comment: @sumant tried that as well - no joy

Comment: strange imgetting Errormessage: Access denied for user 'halaalre_rt'@'localhost' (using password: YES)